# Add Component buttons positioned offscreen after upgrade

Tags: experience-editor, upgrade

I recently upgraded one of our Sitecore sites from 8.0 to 8.1 update 3, which mostly went smoothly.

Since the upgrade, in Experience Editor when adding components, the "Add component" buttons aren't appearing below certain renderings. They appear above the renderings.

[image: Missing button]

Inspecting in Chrome dev tools shows they missing buttons are there but positioned at `top: 0px; left: 0px;` and as such are behind the ribbon bar.

[image: Dev Tools position]

This wasn't happening before the upgrade, and doesn't affect all renderings -- but there's nothing unusual about the ones it is affecting.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to because of a rendering that's meant to display latest news in the standard values that was producing no markup at all.

Added a quick `if (Html.Glass().IsInEditingMode) {...}` check to render something if in editing mode and there aren't any news articles, and all is well with the world.

Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

It is common for there to be stylesheet and javascript changes with new Sitecore updates. Make sure:

1. You have cleared your browser cache and any Sitecore cookies.
2. Your deployment method successfully overwrites the /sitecore directory on your web server(s)

The first is usually the fix for content authors. The second is a little harder to track down, but can be determined by grabbing a zip file of the Sitecore website folder off of dev.sitecore.net (make sure you select the correct version) and comparing it with your install.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately its neither of those things. Browser cache is definitely cleared (tried multiple browsers; incognito mode, etc). This occurs locally as well as on deployed servers. Any idea which javascript is used to generate and position those buttons?